# torch tensor changes to numpy array in for/while loop?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

```
print('\nCollecting experience')
for ep in range(400):
  state = env.reset()
  #print(state.shape)
  #state = np.array(state)
  state = state.transpose((2, 0, 1))
  #state = torch.from_numpy(state)
  state = Variable(torch.from_numpy(state))
  state = state.unsqueeze(0)
  print("AA", state.shape)
  episode_reward = 0
  step = 0

  for i in range(50):
    # env.render()
    print("BB",state.shape)
    action = agent.get_action(state)
```

i have tried and it works without the loop, it doesn't work with while loop either

---

what is printed:

```
Collecting experience
AA torch.Size([1, 1, 84, 84])
BB torch.Size([1, 1, 84, 84])
BB (84, 84, 1)
```

what is causing the second BB print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, turns out the problem was later in the loop, the next input wasn't the same, so made the processing into numpy and things into a function, and it worked